# Low latency Camera Live Feed

Tags: camera, 25fps

What (if possible) is the best solution (or product) a Camera (or webcam) to get a Video Live Feed in low resolution (640x480 or if possible 960x720) but with extremely low latency (it must be the lowest possible, I hope <20ms) The connection must be any type of Wireless connection (not necessary wifi/BT any type of RF)

I need to get the feed on a computer to process it using opencv

Currently I'm doing some tests using my android phone and an IPWebcam app but the best result I can get is around 20fps (50ms video latency and 4ms of video processing) and that is not enough.

I hope to get 30+ fps

The camera will be mounted on a RC robot that can will run fast (not very fast about 2m/sec^2) so a quick autofocus should be useful